# Polish Notation Expression (need little help) **/^a-bc+d*ef**

Tags: infix-notation, polish-notation, prefix-notation

```
/^a-bc+d*ef
```

I am little bit confused about this expression

```
*ef=(e*f)

+d*ef=d+(e*f)

-BC=(b-c)

/^a? if it is ^23= 2^3
```

here I am confused, what should I do? please need help.

---

```
/^a-bc+d*ef

/^a-bc+d(e*f)
```

Here now what should i do? should `/^a-bc+d+(e*f)` is this okay?

`(b-c)` then what sign should be between `/^a(b-c)` and `d+(e*f)`?

and `/^a` I know if `^23=2^3=8`

but here I am totally fed up. Please guide me where i am wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take a moment to check out the [Tour], and there's some useful information here: [ask] and also here:[mcve].  There are a number of tools online to help with Polish Notation.  What have you tried so far? Also, when you have more information about your Question, you can add it to the original Question with an [edit].  I'm going to move the information you added from the Answer to your Question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not (yet) a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your expression is not correct:

/^a-bc+d*ef

<=>

/^a-bc+d(e*f)

<=>

/^a-bc (d+(e*f))

At this point you've got three values in a row and no operator. All operators should be binary for Polish notation to work.

Comment: a^(b-c)/d+(e*f) i think this should be ,